# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

App.js:

```
function App() {
  PreProcess();
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);   // user initialized to null
  return user ?
    (
      <p>{user}</p>
    )
    :
    (<p>Authenticating and Authorizing</p>)
}

export default App;
```

preProcess.js:

```
export const PreProcess = async () => {
    await readEnvVars();  // read env vars in local json file
    Auth();   // need environment variables for authentication and authorization
}
```

auth.js

```
export const Auth = async () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // some logic for authentication and authorization to get the user

    dispatch(setUser(userId));
}
```

Received error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
> called inside of the body of a function component.

at auth.js:

`const dispatch = useDispatch();`

Why do I get this error and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by moving the `const dispatch = useDispatch();` up to App.js and pass the dispatch var as an argument to the method needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks cannot be called inside plain javascript functions, only within another hooks, or in function components.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I remember I got this warning, so I changed the function name to upper case to make it a React function component and the warning went away. Anyway, it is not working, any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Auth is not a function component or a hook, so your code doesn't work.